# Group size difference on random grouping

Tags: probability

I was wondering if someone can help me with the following problem:

I roll a fair, **m** sided dice **n** times and count how many times each side was rolled. What is the expected value of the difference between the most and least rolled sides?

E.g. I have a 6 sided dice which I roll 100 times. I experience that I rolled

- 1 17 times
- 2 18 times
- 3 21 times
- 4 12 times
- 5 21 times
- 6 11 times

So the difference is `21 - 11 = 10`. I'm interested in the expected value of this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Due to linearity of expectation, this is the expected value of the highest count minus the expected value of the lowest count. I doubt you'll find closed forms for these. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/47475) at stats.stackexchange has something on this.